# Applications of the co-area formula

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Kirchheim [2] generalized the classical area formula to the case of Lipschitz mappings into metric spaces. Ths paper is well known and widely cited. The area formula is a special case of the co-area formula. The classical co-area formula has plenty of applications.

On the other I am quite surprised that the co-area formula for mappings into metric spaces [1,3] is not that widely cited and I did not see too many applications. Are you aware of interesting applications of this general version of the co-area formula (i.e. for Lipschitz mappings into metric spaces)?

For the record, the theorem is:

**Theorem:** Suppose $X$ is an $\mathcal{H}^n$-$\sigma$-finite metric space, $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is measurable and $f\colon A \to X$ is Lipschitz. Then, for any integrable $g$ on $A$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} g(x) C_n(\text{md}(f,x)) \ d\mathcal{H}^{n+m}(x) = \int_{X} \left( \int_{f^{-1}(\{y\}) \cap A} g  d\mathcal{H}^{m}  \right)  d\mathcal{H}^n(y) \ .
\end{equation}
Here $\text{md}(f,x)$ is the so-called *metric derivative* of $f$ at $x$, which is a seminorm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, and $C_n(\text{md}(f,x))$ is its *coarea factor* -- some sort of $n$-Jacobian.

[1] **M. Karmanova,**
Rectifiable sets and coarea formula for metric-valued mappings.
*J. Funct. Anal.* 254 (2008), 1410–1447.

[2] **B. Kirchheim**, Rectifiable metric spaces: local structure and regularity of the Hausdorff measure. *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 121 (1994), no. 1, 113–123.

[3] **L. P. Reichel**,
*The coarea formula for metric space valued maps.* Ph.D. thesis, ETH Zurich, 2009.
(Available online).

Comment: I have seen it arise in the study of Gromov--Hausdorff limits of Kähler manifolds.

Comment: @ABitTooCurious Any reference to that?

Comment: Not exactly, but a starting point might be the recent (March 2019) paper of Song--Tian--Zhang on the collapsing behavior of Ricci-flat Kähler metrics and long-time behavior of the KRF.